# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 410D0AAC from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to create a client and a server that communicate via sockets, and I need both server and client to be able to pass LinkedLists through sockets. To that end I'm trying to use ObjectInputStreams and ObjectOutputStreams, but even though in the Server they work perfectly in the Client throws an ObjectInputStream Exception. Anyone knows why could that happen?

Server:

```
public class DedicatedServer extends Thread{

    ServerSocket listener;
    Socket s;

    Manager m;

    public DedicatedServer(ServerSocket listener, Socket s) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.s = s;
        m = new Manager();
    }

    public void run(){

        String request;

        while (true) {

            try{

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println("A");

                //DataInputStream dataInput = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                objectOut.flush();
                ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

                boolean serverOn = true;

                while(serverOn){

                    try{

                        request = (String)objectIn.readObject();
                        if(request.equals("RU")){

                            objectOut.writeObject(m.getUsuaris());

                        }

                        if(request.equals("WU")){

                            Usuari u = (Usuari)objectIn.readObject();
                            m.addUsuari(u);

                        }

                        if(request.equals("RC")){

                            objectOut.writeObject(m.getCancons());

                        }


                    }catch(Exception e){

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        serverOn = false;

                    }



                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client extends Thread{

    Socket s;
    PrintWriter out;

    //private DataOutputStream dataOut;

    private ObjectInputStream objectIn;

    private ObjectOutputStream objectOut;

    public Client(String host, int port) throws IOException {

        try{

            s = new Socket(host, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            this.objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            objectOut.flush();
            this.objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public void run(){

        try {

            //Scanner in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());


            while(true){



                //System.out.println("Server response: " + in.nextLine());

            }

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public Object sendMessage(String message){

        try{
            objectOut.writeObject(message);

            return objectIn.readObject();
        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }

    public void sendObject(Object o){

        try{
            objectOut.writeObject(o);

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 0x410D0A is, guess what, "A\r\n", which is the result of `println("A")`. You can't mix a `PrintWriter` and an `ObjectOutputStream` on the same socket. Use the `ObjectOutputStream` for everything.

Comment: Of course the original error was that you didn't read the `A` line before constructing the `ObjectInputStream` that failed, but there is no good way to do that, and no apparent point to sending it in the first place.